# Transparent image on another image as hover

Tags: image, hover, transparent

I am trying to resolve my problem with image on another picture after hover.

I found this: http://demo.fearlessflyer.com/html/demo/pretty-hovers/ , but i couldn't delete title from it.

My current code is very simple:

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
<img src="img/w.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="img/sr.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="img/as.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery  img { width: 160px; height: 160px; padding: 4px; border: 1px #666 solid; }
```

I would like to avoid place any containers, span, classes, etc. in HTML code. I prefer have it in CSS/JS source.

I wanna similiar effect to:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/eq6phd.jpg

Thanks for any reply.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason forcing you to avoid the usage of div elements? While I believe it is possible to do without these I doubt you´ll find a "nice" solution. I would probably try something like:

html:

```
<div id="gallery">
 ...
 <div id="DivToHover1"><img id="imgToHide" src="yourTransparentPicture"/></div>
 ...
</div>
```

css:

```
...
#DivToHover1 {
  height: "your picture height";
  width: "your picture width";
  background-image:url("yourpicture");
}

#imgToHide {
  display:none;
}
...
```

js:

```
...
$("#DivToHover1").hover(function() {
  $("#imgToHide").show();
  //do some more funky stuff
});
...
```

Comment: ,,Is there a particular reason forcing you to avoid the usage of div elements?" Because i wanna implement this code to my specific Wordpress gallery and need mainly images in div.. Image-Source I must place only in HTML code.

Comment: Topic may be closed, because i edited "Pretty hover" from http://demo.fearlessflyer.com/html/demo/pretty-hovers/. Works fine.